# Simplifying a proof by contradiction: if $a\equiv 1\bmod 5$, then $a^2\equiv 1\bmod5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

Prove the following either by Direct Proof or by Contraposition:

Suppose $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, if $a\equiv 1\pmod 5$, then $a^2\equiv 1\pmod5$

Suppose $a\equiv 1\pmod 5$

Then $5|\left(a-1\right)$, therefore $a-1=5k$

$a^2-1=\left(a-1\right)\left(a+1\right)=5k\left(a+1\right)$

Thus, $a^2-1=5m$ where $m=k\left(a+1\right)$

Hence $a^2\equiv1\pmod5$

So, that is basically a proof by Contraposition, right?

Answer (score 2):

If $ a \equiv 1 (mod 5) $, then multiplying both sides by $a$ we get $ a^2 \equiv a (mod 5) $.

So $a^2$ is congruent to $a$, and by hypothesis $a$ is congruent to 1.

Comment: Oh, is that it?

Comment: @AlexeiMurphy  That's one way, although it is not a proof by contradiction as your question title suggests.

Comment: Oh ok, all good

Sorry, need to rephrase the question

Comment: @AlexeiMurphy I see your edit.  That makes me feel better about struggling to find a proof by contradiction.

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: @AlexeiMurphy Cheers.  Sometimes the obvious is the last thing one thinks of.

Comment: Hi there,

That's the final edited question

Answer (score 1):

In proving this relationship, we need only work with one variable.  There is no need to introduce the $b$ variable in your proof.  Additionally, since we are working in modulus 5, I think it would be best if we avoided talking about odd numbers and stuck to talking about mod 5.  Here is a way to start a proof:

Assume that $a \equiv 1$ (mod $5$).  Then we can write $a= 5k+1$ for some integer $k$.

Now, from here, is there any way we can express $a^2$ as a multiple of $5$ plus one?

Answer (score 0):

If
$a\equiv 1\pmod 5$,
$a = 5n+1$
for some integer $n$.
Therefore
$a^2
= 25n^2+10n+1
= 5(5n+2)+1
$
so
$a^2\equiv 1\pmod 5$.

Comment: Ah ok, I see
<br/>
Um, so, the proof I showed, is that correct, or nearly

Comment: It seems correct to me. It is not a proof by contradiction, but such a proof here would be unusual - our direct proofs are much better.